# Package Java Tomcat Webapp

Tags: maven, tomcat, package, war

I have a Java Web App running on Tomcat. It contains multiple libraries, JavaScripts, images, JSP, CSS, TLD, etc... The libraries are located in the WEB-INF folder. How can I package this app (including its libraries and all necessary files) into a WAR file using Maven so that it can run on another PC?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Just zip everything in `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/<yourapp>` (where `$CATALINA_HOME` is the installation directory of Tomcat and `<yourapp>` the name of the directory containing the WEB-INF directory) and rename the zip file to .war. Be sure to zip the contents of `<yourapp>` only, not the directory itself.

Comment: I am trying to use Maven in order to accomplish this

Comment: There was no mention of Maven in your question. Please update it accordingly.